# Is there an easier way to understand negation of a function result?

Tags: php

I recently had to write a piece of code where I used the following; but it was very confusing for me and took me longer than I should

I keep getting lost by the negation and false turning into true and then back maybe. I end up solving these problems by trial and error.

Here is the code for getting rid of empty elements. NB, perhaps there are better code but I'm interested in knowing how to think this through

```
array_filter($array, "eliminate");

function eliminate($v)
{
   return !(empty($v));
}
```

Comment: I'm just wondering, why don't you just return `empty()`? If you're "getting rid of empty elements" (I'm sure you mean variables here, right?), if `empty()` returns true, that element is empty. In that case, you don't even need `eliminate()` unless you have something else going on you didn't include, or need another function as a placeholder for the future.

Comment: This question clearly needs more people quoting the manual

Comment: @Jared: `array_filter` removes elements when the callback returns `false`.  If he just returned `empty()` it would remove all non-empty elements.

Comment: @Rocket - That certainly answers my question. I think a `Doh('!')` is in order. Thanks!

Comment: I think your problem is due to the name of the function. As Rocket says, the filter removes elements if the callback returns false, retains them if it returns true, so a better name would be "retain".

Answer (score 2):

[`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) takes two arguments.  The first is an array.  The second is a callback.  Here you are using the name of a function contained within a string `"eliminate"` to tell PHP which function you want to invoke.

The purpose of `array_filter` is to remove items from the array if you don't want them.  The function from the second argument is called on every item in the array.  The item is passed as the first argument to that function -- so `$v` in your above code is set to the value of the element we're looking at.  If you return `true` from your callback, the item is kept in the array. If you return `false`, it is removed.

Your function returns true or false based on the following:

```
return !(empty($v));
```

[`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) returns `true` if the element is empty (e.g. an empty string, an empty array, the integer `0`, among others).  The `!` operator turns this around.  So the function will return `false` (and remove the item from the array) if the item is empty.  Otherwise, it will return `true` and keep it.

Your function is approximately equivalent to the following loop:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($oldArray as $key=>$value) {
    if (!empty($value)) {
        $newArray[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterates over each value in the input array passing them to the callback function. If the 
callback function returns true, the current value from input is returned into the result array.
Array keys are preserved.
```

Source: http://php.net/array_filter

Each element is passed to eliminate function. Now inside eliminate if the value passed is empty it will return false and it will not belong in the next array.

**Please note that your code does nothing because you should do:**

```
$newArray=array_filter($array, "eliminate"); //< note the newarray

function eliminate($v)
{
   return !(empty($v));
}
```

Or a better code with PHP 5.3

```
$newArray=array_filter($array, function ($v){
       return !(empty($v));
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

[`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) runs the callback function on each array element.  If the callback returns `true`, the element is kept, if `false` it's removed.

So, for every element in `$array`, it checks if it's `empty()`.  If it's not, it gets to stay in the array, if it is it leaves.  `empty()` returns `true` if it's empty (which means we want it removed from the array), so we need to return `false`.

If you call `array_filter` without a callback, it remove things that convert to `false`, so in your case `$array = array_filter($array);` should work.

`array_filter` returns you the modified array.

Comment: Wow, thank you guys for all the code and explanation. Although I knew what the code was doing, I still found it hard following the train of thought to write it out. I keep flipping, and fillping. I don't mean for this case in particular but just to give an example. I can't seem to think of it clearly. Maybe I'm just not studying it right way

Answer (score 0):

The best way to think about this code is by "talking" it out:

Let's start with `eliminate`, `eliminate` returns `true` when `$v` is not empty, `false` otherwise

Now, `array_filter` applies the designated function, here it's `eliminate`, to every element in `$array`, one at a time.

Finally, we need to understand that if, for some single element `$v` in `$array`, `eliminate($v)` returns `true`, then that element is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
array_filter($array);
```

This will eliminate every empty element of the array - the result should be identical to the code you have shown (with 'eliminate' function and `!(empty($v))` code).